# "X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0"

Tags: centos6, x11-forwarding

I have tried all ways to configure the X11 forward .but it still failed .
the X11forward yes ,and Xauth is installed and so on .
but when I type ssh -Xv mydomain
it still have error 
"X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0"

i feel really confused the reason why it has error

could you help on this please

thanks

Answer (score 12):

This is not documented well and the option is no longer in the default config, which further complicates the issue. You need to add the config entry that enables Xforwarding from any host not just localhost.

Try adding

```
X11UseLocalhost no
```

to

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Comment: You've saved me a lot of anguish, my friend. It's terribly confusing that `X11Forwarding yes` still means "no" for everything but localhost (where forwarding is usually unnecessary anyway).